# Object reference not set to an instance of an object stringBuilder.Append(string.Format());

Tags: html, asp.net

I try to display the table using StringBuilder but it does not work. It causes an error say "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"  at sb.Append(string.Format(. Please help. Thank you.

```
            foreach (Item item in list)
            {

                sb.Append(string.Format(
                    @"<table >
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan ='6' width='150px'><img runat='server' src='{3}'/>
                            </th>
                            <th width='50px'>Title: </th>
                            <td>{0}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Price:</th>
                            <td>{1}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Available: </th>
                            <td>{2}</td>                                
                        </tr>
                    </table>",  item.ItemAttributes.Publisher,item.ItemAttributes.ListPrice.ToString(), item.ItemAttributes.NumberOfItems, item.SmallImage.URL));
                lblItemResponse.Text = sb.ToString();


            }
```

Comment: With just the code, it will not be possible. You need to put a debugger and see which object of item there is null value.

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint in this line lblItemResponse.Text = sb.ToString(); and hover all the objects to find out which item is null.

Comment: BTW, call `AppendFormat()`

Comment: I just don't know what happened but when I add try/catch in, every thing works well.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.